# Unable to Connect to WiFi router from Ubuntu

Tags: networking, dual-boot, 22.04, windows-10, nic

I have a dual boot setup with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Now there is a issue with my Ubuntu operating system not being able to connect to my router, but interestingly, i can connect to the WiFi router from the Windows operating system and other devices such as an Android phone.

Previously, Ubuntu was also able to connect to the WiFi router without any issues. However, after i booted into Windows (to use a windows software), and then booted back into Ubuntu,  it's not able to connect to the WiFi router again.

When i'm booted into Ubuntu and try to connect to my WiFi, the connection is being timedout, and noting happens.  I've also tried changing configuration to be the same as my other devices, but it doesnt make a difference.

I've tried diagnosing the issue, but It's challenging by the fact that tools such as `ifconfig`, `ifdown` and `network-manager` is not installed on the Ubuntu partition either. However I've tried using WireShark to capture and inspect network packages, but there is no packets being sent from my computer whenever i try to connect to the router.

**Here is some of things i've already tried:**

- Disabling firewall
- Disabling ipv6
- Disable fast startup (in windows power settings)
- Use static IP and set manually configuration to WiFi
- Adding route https://www.poftut.com/add-new-route-ubuntu-linux/ (followed this guide)
- Changing band selection from automatic to force 2.4GHz

Additional information about wireless info:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/nFz7GpCn9d/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: A partition is part of a hard drive storage space. I think you mean Operating system.

Comment: Thanks david, text is updated now